# Scattered hCard data for one organization

Tags: html, seo, vcf-vcard, microformats, hcard

I'm designing a site for an organization, and only some of the organization's hCard data is included in the site's footer at the moment. Some information, such as fax and a toll free number, has been included only on the home and contact pages.

How would a search engine merge this data? Should multiple hCard containers for the same entity be included on the same page if it's spread out? Should every page include the same hCard in the site-wide footer? How complete should it be?

The following would produce something like "Copyright © 2014 [Company Name](http://example.com/)." Should the site url and entity name be separated? Can it be improved?

```
<?=$copyright?> <span class="fn org"><a href="<?=base_url()?>" class="url fn org"><?=$company?></a></span>
```

What about compressing it further by removing the span, as in the following?

```
<?=$copyright?> <a href="<?=base_url()?>" class="url fn org"><?=$company?></a>
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is asking about behavior of search engine services / SEO. It might belong on [webmasters.se].

Comment: its also asking about html, semantic markup, machine tags, and linked data. not sure why you think seo singles it out for movement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would make one complete hcard and place it in your footer. and everything that is not desired i would set to `display:none`, perhaps even `text-indent:-9999px`, if fitting. considering its the info for the company the site is about, it's not blackhat. you're just utilizing microformats more for bots than humans in this case. that's not a bad thing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I decided to use microdata (schema.org) to take advantage of the meta element, allowing a more fleshed-out card without bulking up the footer, and http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets for testing.